# Modify value in iterator of a for-each loop

Tags: swift3

I currently started with learning Swift 3 (I already have experience with other programming languages) and asked me the question if I can modify a value inside of an iterator of a for-each loop (not for-in!). Let's take a look at the following example:

```
var numbers = [45000.0, 50000.0, 60000.0]

for i in 0..<numbers.count {
    numbers[i] = numbers[i] + (numbers[i] * 0.1)   
}
```

In this example, I could modify the value inside of the array. But if I want to use the for-each loop:

```
for number in numbers {
    number = number + (number * 0.1)
}
```

it will not compile. Is it possible in any other way to modify the value of number (which seems to me like an iterator in C++)?

Thanks for all answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible using your example because `Array<Double>` is value type and the index variable `number` is a constant. To make `number` mutable you have to copy it which leaves the original item in the array unchanged.

A *compromise* is the `enumerated()` function.

```
var numbers = [45000.0, 50000.0, 60000.0]

for (i, number) in numbers.enumerated() {
    numbers[i] = number + (number * 0.1)
}
```

However the solution suggested by Sulthan is preferable.

Comment: It would be much better (and more Swifty) to use `map` here. For loops are "old school" haha

Comment: I know, but I wanted to answer the question literally.

Comment: OK, fair enough :)

Answer (score 7):

You are still thinking in terms of old programming languages. The modern approach is to do everything in one step using a helper function, without using manual iteration:

```
let numbers = [45000.0, 50000.0, 60000.0]
let newNumbers = numbers.map { $0 + $0 * 0.1 }
```

Note we have generated a new array instead of changing the existing one. The use of constants (immutables) helps us to avoid many common programming mistakes.